# How to add color themes to Gnome-Terminal's GUI preferences?

Tags: colors, gnome-terminal

I use Gnome-Terminal for a lot of my work, and like separating my windows by color based on the task that I'm doing, so I've set up several profiles using the Preferences GUI.

I found some color themes online that I like and would like to use as a base for some of my profiles, including any that I create in the future. However, the Preferences GUI only has a few color theme options, and I would need to change all of the colors manually any time I want to use one of these custom themes.

Is there a way I can add custom themes to my Preferences GUI? If that's not possible, is there another way I can easily set a custom color theme for a profile? I know I can manually change the colors in other places, like gconf-editor, but I'd prefer an easy way to just tell it the color theme by name and have it handle the rest (like what you can do with the GUI).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The color palettes are all hard-coded so adding custom themes to gnome-terminal built-in Prefs Menu is not possible unless you are willing to patch the source code and recompile the application.

One way of setting a custom color themes for your profile is via scripts. Have a look at how [solarize](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) does it:

[gnome-terminal-colors-solarized](https://github.com/sigurdga/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized)

Note, though, that gconf is EOL and future releases of gnome-terminal [will use *gsettings* backend.](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeGoals/GSettingsMigration)

Comment: Note that Solarized now recommends you create a new profile and set up the theme as the "custom" theme there.

Comment: Gnome is so retardedly moving away from the Linux philosophy... They will burry their own grave in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The [Gogh theme picker](https://gogh-co.github.io/Gogh/) allows you to install 200+ different themes for the Gnome terminal. From the website, it tells you to run this command:

```bash
bash -c  "$(wget -qO- https://git.io/vQgMr)"
```

I'm not a fan of short URLs as you never know where they lead, so you can replace the above with this if you prefer:

```bash
bash -c  "$(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mayccoll/Gogh/master/gogh.sh)"
```

What that does is open a bash prompt that allows you to select a theme by number.

[image]

For example `194` is Solarized Light, which then adds it to your Gnome Terminal Profiles

[image]